# I want to create a jquery for conversion of gold to amount and vice versa

Tags: c#, jquery

**Problem Description :** I want to create jquery method from where i can convert *gold weight* to *amount by multiplying* it from gold rate f.e `50*2000=100000` and vice versa also that is Amount to Gold by dividing it from gold rate f.e `100000/2000=50`

```
Amount=GoldWeight*GoldRate; // TOP DOWN APPROACH
GoldWeight=Amount/GoldRate; // BOTTOM UP APPROACH
```

But at the same if all textbox have values it should convert gold if we change amount and also amount if we change in gold value....Please help me in this..

Comment: @JSantosh check answer below i posted..focusin and focusout to handle values from top to bottom and vice versa...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the Answer

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  $('#txtGoldConverted').focusin(function() {
    var r = $('#txtAmount').val();
    var q = $('#txtGoldRate').val();
    if (r != "" && q != "") {
      var p = r / q;
      var res = p.toFixed(3);
      var resRound = (Math.round(res * 100)) / 100;
      $('#txtGoldConverted').val(resRound);
    }
  });

  $('#txtGoldConverted').focusout(function() {
    var p = $('#txtGoldConverted').val();
    var q = $('#txtGoldRate').val();
    if (p != "" && q != "") {
      var r = p * q;
      $('#txtAmount').val(r);
    }

  });

  $('#txtGoldRate').focusout(function() {
    var p = $('#txtGoldConverted').val();
    var q = $('#txtGoldRate').val();
    var r = p * q;
    $('#txtamount').val(r);
  });

  $('#txtAmount').focusin(function() {
    var p = $('#txtGoldConverted').val();
    var q = $('#txtGoldRate').val();
    if (p != "" && q != "") {
      var r = p * q;
      $('#txtAmount').val(r);
    }
  });

  $('#txtAmount').focusout(function() {
    var r = $('#txtAmount').val();
    var q = $('#txtGoldRate').val();
    if (r != "" && q != "") {
      var p = r / q;
      var res = p.toFixed(3);
      var resRound = (Math.round(res * 100)) / 100;
      $('#txtGoldConverted').val(res);
    }
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `focusout()` function on your both Textboxes inorder to Change one Value Based on Other

**Example**

```
$('#goldbox').focusout(function(){
   var newamount;
   //calculate money value based on gold
   $('#moneybox').val(newamount);
});
```

Comment: Thanks @rajan ks ..i tried your suggestion...and its done

Comment: I posted the answer also based on your suggestion and its working great...thnks again

Comment: Welcome :) Upvote to Promote Answers that are Working :)